# How can I add captions to videos?

Tags: software-recommendation, software

I'm looking forward a way to add captions like some media companies do, in order to inform some news or tell a story on Facebook videos. Take Futurism videos as an example: https://www.facebook.com/futurism/videos

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? *Captions* can mean different things (e.g., [closed captioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_captioning) and [lower thirds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_third)). What type of videos? What level of professionalism? What is your target audience? How are you distributing the videos?